# Jena DataAccessorFactory with the parliament triplestore?

Tags: rdf, jena, triplestore, parliament

I have successfully used DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://localhost:3030/test/data"); to access rdf data on Fuseki.

I was wondering if it is possible to use this same technique with Parliament triplestore? And if not, what is the best way for injecting a Jena model into Parliament?

Kind regards,

Kris.

Comment: Trying it out is no solution? And Jena can be used with any triple store via HTTP if the SPARQL protocol is supported correctly.

Comment: I did try. I tried using http://localhost:8089/parliament/, but it throws a socket error - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error. Also tried parliament/sparql

Comment: Just to clarify, it throws a socket error when I try to use .add(model) (where model is a org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model), this works fine for Fuseki

Comment: I would have given up all hope, but here lieth some code which appears to do this very thing, they just don't specify the url for parliament - https://github.com/BBN-E/Adept/blob/master/adept-kb/src/main/java/adept/kbapi/RemoteSPARQLService.java

Comment: for me it looks like Parliament is more than 2 years old and based on Jena 2.x at the time of writing. what's the reason for using it at all instead of Fuseki?

Comment: Parliament has nice support for GeoSPARQL. Fuseki also should support GeoSPARQL, but last time I tried to configure it for GeoSPARQL I failed.

Comment: @Kris fwiw RDF4J has some support for GeoSPARQL as well, and if you prefer the Jena APIs you could just use an RDF4J Server and access it via SPARQL protocol from Jena (disclosure: am an rdf4j dev).

Comment: @Kris afaik, Jena doesn't support GeoSPARQL (see the [docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html)), thus, I don't know what you tried to configure.

Comment: @Jeen Broekstra I would really prefer avoiding moving to yet another rdf server.

Comment: @AKSW FYI here is a Jena ARQ extension for GeoSPARQL - https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html. As for my original question, it is related to using Jena to add a model to Parliament. Parliament supports GeoSPARQL. I thought it would be an easy process to add a Jena model to a Parliament triplestore, but turns out it isn't. I could do an update query and add all the RDF statements that way, but to be honest, I am also thinking I might try and configure fuseki instead for GeoSPARQL.

Comment: Well, it's the same link a shared with you - and to make it clear, it is **not** official GeoSPARQL vocabulary but an own implementation, please look at the namespace of the supported predicates.

Comment: Anyways, you could also try to ask on the Jena mailing list for support, those guys are pretty fast in answering and always happy to help.

Comment: Indeed, if the spatial predicates supported by JEna are enough, you could go with it, but GeoSPARQL queries won't work given that it contains much more predicates under a different namespace that won't be interpreted correctly by Jena - (if I'm not totally wrong, AndyS and RobV know this better than me for sure)

Comment: @AKSW Once you insert your rdf into Parliament, it will automatically index your GeoSPARQL (after you index for the first time) and then support geospatial functions (such as sfWithin). So, I can get my rdf model and insert it into the kb using the web client functionality of Parliament, and run my queries over it, no problem. But if I want to add the rdf model using the DatasetAccessor in the Jena libraries from some java code I have developed...no go. DatasetAccessor works fine with fuseki though.